# Using variable input for system()

Tags: r

I am using an executable made from C, and I am trying to pass variables in R to it.

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int sumUp(int x, int y, int z, int *sum);

int main()
{
    int x1,x2,x3;
    int total = 0;

    scanf("%d %d %d",&x1,&x2,&x3);
    sumUp(x1,x2,x3,&total);
    printf("Your total is :%d\n", total);

    system("pause");

}

int sumUp(int x, int y, int z, int *sum)
{
    *sum = x + y + z;
}
```

and Here is my R code:

```
x <- 0
y <- 0
z <- 0

readint <-function(){
  a <- readline(prompt = "Enter a number: \n")
}

x <- as.numeric(readint())
y <- as.numeric(readint())
z <- as.numeric(readint())

system("Practice.exe", intern = TRUE,input = "x y z")
```

I am having an issue when I use variables for `input` as it will print an incorrect value. However, when I use direct input, like `input = "1 2 3"`, I will get the correct answer. I checked the types for for my variables, and they seem to be correct. Here is the output for reference:[image][image]

Is there something wonky going on between R and C, or am I doing something incorrect with `system`? Even if I vary the values of `x,y,z`, I will get `84`. So I imagine there is something going on under the hood here that I am missing. I tried using `args` instead of `input`, but ran into the same issue, except that it gave a value of `126` no matter what I entered, variable or directly. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: First thing first, remove `system("pause")` from your C code, it has no place in non-interactive programs and is unnecessary beyond that in 99.99% of cases. Secondly, you’re using the `input` parameter incorrectly in R. You’re supposed to pass a character vector of the *actual values* here, not of variable names.

Comment: Third, quoting the help page, `system2` *is recommended for new code.*

Comment: @KonradRudolph Is there a proper way to pass input to an executable by variable name?

Comment: @hkj447 You need to pass the *values*. Check out the `paste` function for converting multiple values to string and concatenating them.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Paste worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rather do this in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int sumUp(int x, int y, int z, int *sum);

int main()
{
    int x1,x2,x3;
    int total = 0;
    x1 = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    x2 = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);
    x3 = strtol(argv[3], NULL, 10);

    sumUp(x1,x2,x3,&total);
    printf("Your total is :%d\n", total);

    system("pause");

}

int sumUp(int x, int y, int z, int *sum)
{
    *sum = x + y + z;
}
```

And this in R:

```
x <- 0
y <- 0
z <- 0

readint <-function(){
  a <- readline(prompt = "Enter a number: \n")
}

x <- as.numeric(readint())
y <- as.numeric(readint())
z <- as.numeric(readint())
cmd <- paste("Practice.exe", x, y, z)
system(cmd, intern = TRUE)
```